# Cannot statically evaluate fs argument?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, user-interface, npm

While running `npm run dev`, the below error popped up.

```
Cannot statically evaluate fs argument
[0]   50 |   // Read file and split into lines
[0]   51 |   var map = {},
[0] > 52 |       content = fs.readFileSync(file, 'ascii'),
[0]      |                                ^
[0]   53 |       lines = content.split(/[\r\n]+/);
[0]   54 |
[0]   55 |   lines.forEach(function(line) {
```

Comment: What tool is generating this error? It sounds like the kind of error you'd get from a bundler like Webpack or Rollup, not any of the tools listed  in the tags. My guess is that you have this in server-side code but accidentally have the bundler trying to bundle it. (Bundlers don't like non-static filenames because they don't know what the file is, which means they can't ensure the file is in the bundle and access it correctly.)

Comment: did you add `const fs = require('fs');` with your imports. I also don't understand why there are commas after each line. Is this the output from the build folder? In normal development code, it should be semi-colons to terminate a line.

Comment: @VPaul it's just a variable declaration for multiple identifiers. You can declare `var a, b, c` fine and even add an initialiser for them `var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3` is a perfectly valid declaration statement.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for noting it. I didn't see there is a semicolon used before the loop.

Comment: Your question needs more detail or clarity. because you should pass the `content = fs.readFileSync(file, 'ascii'),` whole code and also write your desire. for example why you should use `fs`. for uploading an image? or something else.

Answer (score -2):

Look at your dependencies may you need `npm install` again and if you have problem with some packages then you have to install it manually like `npm install mailgun`

Comment: Your answer is based on something that is not spoken of by the asker, try commenting to the askers post and if there is no response for clarity then the question may not have enough information for the correct answer.